# How can I accept licenses for android sdk in gitlab ci

Tags: android, google-play, gitlab-ci, fastlane

I'm trying to deploy automatically to google play using fastlane and android-ci but I'm receiving this:

License for package Android SDK Platform 30 not accepted

Comment: Can you confirm if your docker image contains the following: `RUN yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: I tried this, but it says sdkmanager is not present